# Poblems with running ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-ajax

I don't have enough skill in jQuery.
I wrote an ajax for comment section in web page but it doesn't work.I want to send a commend to an action and after that clear the comment box.

```html
<h6> enter your comment </h6>
    <form class="comment-form" action="" method="post">
        <div>
            <input placeholder=" Full Name" type="text" id="txtName">
            <input placeholder=" Email " type="email" id="txtEmail">
            <input placeholder=" Mobile " type="text" id="txtPhoneNumber">

        </div>
        <textarea placeholder=" Comment" id="txtComment"> </textarea>
        <input value="Send your comment " type="button" onclick="addComment()" >
    </form>
</section>

<script type="text/javascript">
  
    function addComment() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/News/AddComment/" +@Model.PageID,
            type: "Get",
            data: { name: $("#txtName").val(), email: $("#txtEmail").val(), text: $("#txtComment").val(), number: $("#txtPhoneNumber").val() }
            
        }).done(function () {

            $("#txtName").val("");
            $("#txtEmail").val("");
            $("#txtPhoneNumber").val("");
            $("#txtComment").val("");
        });
    }
    
</script>
```

it doesn't the comment to action and it doesn't clear the comment box too.

Comment: Do you receive any error in console or network activity tab?

Comment: No I didn't any error in consol

Comment: do you prevent the form from normal submition?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Get Use Post, it might help
Also try this if u can receive any error or success in console

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

     function addComment() {
       $.ajax({
          url: "/News/AddComment/" +@Model.PageID,
          type: "Get",
          data: { name: $("#txtName").val(), email: $("#txtEmail").val(), 
           text: $("#txtComment").val(), number:  
           $("#txtPhoneNumber").val() },
       success: function(response){
      console.log(response);
      }
     });
    }

   </script>
```

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer

Comment: sorry bro i am replying from cell thats why, didnt catched it

Comment: See the token, You might be missing commas or semicolons, its a syntax error